# Calling a C library in python?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, scipy, cython

I want to call functions from a C++ library in a python code, and I don't how it should be done. I am wondering whether it is possible to use numpy.array as input for C++ pointers or whether I need to modify them to transfer from python to C?

Comment: http://csl.name/C-functions-from-Python/

Comment: I am closing this as a duplicate. If you feel that there is part of the question not answered by the duplicate, please separate it into a new question that is clearly distinct from the referenced question.

Answer (score 0):

Similar questions have already been discussed on stackoverflow. Here are some of them:

1. [Calling C/C++ from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)
2. [Calling C functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647186/calling-c-functions-in-python)
3. [Wrapping a C library in Python: C, Cython or ctypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942298/wrapping-a-c-library-in-python-c-cython-or-ctypes)

About using `numpy.array` as input for C/C++ function look the answers to the similar question here:
[Passing Numpy arrays to a C function for input and output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862915/passing-numpy-arrays-to-a-c-function-for-input-and-output)