# Python Curses init_pair implementation not matching the documentation

Tags: python, ncurses, cpython, curses

I've been experimenting with Curses colors and ran into a bit of an issue.

As the documentation of `init_pair` states, the first argument (the number of the pair) shall be between `1` and `curses.COLOR_PAIRS - 1`. Doing `print(curses.COLOR, curses.COLOR_PAIR)` yields `256 65536`, so one would think that calling `courses.init_pair(40000, 1, 53)` (random example) would work, but I get an error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "4-colors.py", line 38, in <module>
    curses.wrapper(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/curses/__init__.py", line 105, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "4-colors.py", line 18, in main
    curses.init_pair(40000, 1, 53)
OverflowError: signed short integer is greater than maximum
```

Sure enough, [the implementation of init_color](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/clinic/_cursesmodule.c.h#L2597) (I hope that I'm looking at the right file) checks whether the color pair number is within bounds of a signed short.

Why? Is there a way to bypass this and use all of the colors of my
terminal, not just an arbitrary half?

---

Full source code of the MWE:

```
import curses

def main(window):
    curses.start_color()
    curses.use_default_colors()

    curses.init_pair(40000, 1, 53)

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: I agree that you've found a legitimate bug here - but I fail to see any real-world impact from the bug.  Your screen is certainly not displaying 32768 characters at the same time; you could assign a separate color pair to each character on the screen, so you aren't actually being limited in any way.

Comment: I am, since I would like to use all of the `256^2` of foreground-background color combinations. I realize that one could dynamically map currently unused pairs numbers, but that would be such a pain to program...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Python's curses binding was not updated to account for the changes made in [ncurses 6.1](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-6.1.html): before that point, *capability values* (numbers) passed to/from the curses library were limited to a signed 16-bit number.  ncurses 6.1 extended that, although to make effective use of things like `COLOR_PAIRS`, it is necessary to use one of the function extensions introduced in ncurses 6.1

In the given example, for instance, rather than calling [`init_pair`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-init_pair), whose C prototype is

```
int init_pair(short pair, short f, short b);
```

one would use [`init_extended_pair`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-init_extended_pair):

```
int init_extended_pair(int pair, int f, int b);
```

Of course, it's ***always*** been the case that applications are responsible for validating the numbers that they deal with.  The example shown illustrates a Python runtime exception (rather than for example limiting the number of color pairs seen by callers).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the answer! Do you think that there would be a way to do this from Python, or do I just have to wait for the bindings to get updated?

Comment: You might wait a while (opening a bug report might get some action).  It involves adding/modifying code (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647186/calling-c-functions-in-python)).